# Pass List as parameter to MVC controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I try to do a thing I do **everywhere** in my code and for an unknown reason I can't do here.

I try to pass a list of object to my controller but I can't map my array into my list.

View :

```
var interventions = [
    {
        Id: 1,
        Title: 'Intervention 1',
        ToDoBefore: new Date(),
        PlannedDate: new Date()
    },
    {
        Id: 2,
        Title: 'Intervention 2',
        ToDoBefore: new Date(),
        PlannedDate: new Date()
    },
]

$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/AffectToSubcontractors',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(interventions),
    success: function (result) {
        debugger;
    }
});
```

Controller :

```
    public PartialViewResult AffectToSubcontractors(List<SelectedInterventionsViewModel> interventions)
    {
        // Do something
    }
```

Model :

```
public class SelectedInterventionsViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public DateTime ToDoBefore { get; set; }

    public DateTime PlannedDate { get; set; }
}
```

What I miss ?

Comment: You're missing the details of your error and a description of what you expect instead.

Comment: Oh. Yes, of course. The `interventions` parameter in my controller is an empty list instead of a list of two.

Comment: Is your method marked `[HttpPost]`?

Comment: I tried this but no effect. And I try too to mark the argument `[FromBody]` but with the same result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[HttpPost]` decoration on my controller method solved the problem. Don't ask me why. Usually I don't set it and it works. And why the method is called but the parameter is not sent ? I don't know either...

Comment: Default is HTTP GET, so by setting the HttpPost attribute, you changed it to HTTP POST instead.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any thing missing in your code yet I have tried the same code you mentioned and found the collection. The c# part could not have error there may be some problem in view. I tried like below on index.chtml please try your code in clean view.

```
 @ViewBag.Title  Home
<div>     
    <div>
      <script >
          var interventions = [
    {
        Id: 1,
        Title: 'Intervention 1',
        ToDoBefore: new Date(),
        PlannedDate: new Date()
    },
    {
        Id: 2,
        Title: 'Intervention 2',
        ToDoBefore: new Date(),
        PlannedDate: new Date()
    },
          ]

          $.ajax({
              url: '/Home/AffectToSubcontractors',
              contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
              dataType: 'json',
              type: 'POST',
              data: JSON.stringify(interventions),
              success: function (result) {
                  debugger;
              }
          });
      </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to come back here... My code work I added the `[HttpPost]` tag on my controller method and all be good after that. I don't know why, usually I didn't mentionne it and it works...